# Objective-C/Swift regex matching across multliple lines

Tags: javascript, python, objective-c, regex, swift

I have a regular expression originally used in python to extract 2 strings from a scraped HTML page : `var\s+kaynaklar.*?url\s*:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"\s*,\s*data\s*:\s*'([^']+)`

This works fine in Python but not in Objective-C/Swift.

This is the Swift 2.0 code I'm using to find the results:

```
do {
        let regexString = "var\\s+kaynaklar.*?url\\s*:\\s*\\\"([^\\\"]+)\\\"\\s*,\\s*data\\s*:\\s*'([^']+)"
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexString, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
            options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
```

And this is an example of the JS being checked inside the HTML looks like :

```
var kaynaklar = [];

jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/service/part",
    data:'id=31398',
    success:function(a){
        if(a=="hata")
        {
            jQuery("#player").html("<br><br><font style='color:white;'>Video kaynağı silinmiş lütfen sol üstten Kaynak butonuna tıklayarak farklı bir kaynak deneyin.</font>")
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                if(a["videolink"+i])
                {
                    kaynaklar.push({"file":a["videolink"+i], "label":a["videokalite"+i],"type":"mp4"});
                }
            }
            video_loader();
        }
    },
    error:function(){
        jQuery("#player").html("<br><br><font style='color:white;'>Video yüklenirken bir hata oluştu lütfen sayfayı yenileyip tekrar deneyin veya farklı bir kaynak deneyin.</font>")
    }
})
```

Comment: Without seeing any Objective-C or Swift code it is a bit difficult to spot what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Did you use double backslashes in Objective C? Like `\\s` instead of `\s`?

Comment: I figured it out in the end, I needed to extract 2 string wrapped in the () to build a new HTTP request. The regex wasn't working because of the new lines in the html, i used "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString" to remove \n and everything is now working great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your feedback, I see you just need to tell the regex engine to match a newline with a period.

Use the [`NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators) option:

> Allow `.` to match any character, including line separators.
>   
>   
> Available in OS X v10.7 and later.

As a quicker-to-implement alternative, use an inline `(?s)` modifier at the beginning of the pattern:

```
let regexString = "(?s)var\\s+kaynaklar.*?url\\s*:\\s*\\\"([^\\\"]+)\\\"\\s*,\\s*data\\s*:\\s*'([^']+)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU3vV1/1).